# Is a Firebase UID always 28 characters?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am creating security rules for my Firebase project and wanted to add `UIDstring.length == 28` to my database rules. All of my users UIDs are 28 characters, but I wanted to check if they can be any longer or shorter?

Thanks

Answer (score 51, accepted):

A Firebase developer had [this to say](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/5ENGCX8y04M) on their forums:

> I would not rely on a constant length for the UIDs forever.  We chose the current value because it provides a big enough ID space while still being under the 36-character limit for Firebase Analytics user properties.

So, in other words, what you're suggesting may or may not fail in the future, so you probably should find a different way of implementing it that's more future-proof.

Comment: makes the most sense to me

Comment: quite annoying if you concat uid's to make another key and depend on the length

Answer (score 10):

The uid of type string is used to assign to the newly created user. Must be a string between 1 and 128 characters long, inclusive. If not provided, a random uid will be automatically generated.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users

Comment: Although the length of the uid you can assign can be between 1 and 128 characters, this doesn't mean that the length of the auto-generated firebase uid will be between 1 and 128 characters. Look at the uid property in https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#create_a_user

Comment: This answer is helpful if you want to set varchar length of UID in your database. So now you know 128 is the max possible length.