# Google Firebase & Social Network question - How should I structure a post's data so that users can see who "liked" the post

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I’m trying to program a simple social network using Firebase, but I see that if I want each “post” to have a list of users who like the post, the post can become very large very fast.

For example, if 1 post had 1 like, and the user ID was 10 bytes long — the post would be about 10 bytes in size (assuming the rest of the post was negligible).

But if 1 post had 200 likes, and each user ID was 10 bytes long — the post would be about 2000 bytes in size.

I have the feeling that it is physically impossible to circumvent this problem. The only way that I think I could reduce the size of the post would be to store a list of custom usernames that are shorter than the Google Firebase UID property but correspond to unique users.

Is there a better way to do this, or am I just looking at the limits of what is possible?

I also thought that maybe instead of a list of `users_who_liked_the_post` each post should just have a `number_of_likes` property that gets incremented every time a user likes the post, but how would I be able to load the list of users who liked the post? Would it be feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For example, if 1 post had 1 like, and the user ID was 10 bytes long — the post would be about 10 bytes in size (assuming the rest of the post was negligible).

That's a quite common practice.

> But if 1 post had 200 likes, and each user ID was 10 bytes long — the post would be about 2000 bytes in size.

In such cases, you should always be aware of the [1 Mib limit of document size.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#limits)

> The only way that I think I could reduce the size of the post would be to store a list of custom usernames that are shorter than the Google Firebase UID property but correspond to unique users.

I don't think that this approach will actually solve the problem. Why? That's because you always have to check if a user exists, before adding a new one, and this implies costs. If you're using UIDs, then there is nothing to worry about, because the UIDs that are generated by Firebase are completely unique. Besides that, what if your users are choosing usernames that are longer than the UIDs?

> I also thought that maybe instead of a list of users_who_liked_the_post each post should just have a number_of_likes property that gets incremented every time a user likes the post, but how would I be able to load the list of users who liked the post? Would it be feasible?

In this scenario, you'll let the user like a post multiple times. Why? Because if don't add the UID in the post, you don't know if the user already liked or not the post. Using the UID, you can add it when the user likes a post, and remove it when the user retracts the like.

> Is there a better way to do this, or am I just looking at the limits of what is possible?

Your current approach that saves UIDs in the document can solve the problem. However, the only issue is with the limitation, a case in which you can use a workaround. If all the UIDs don't fit into a single document, then you should create two documents, three, or even four. Imagine how many UIDs can fit into 4  MiB?

I recently answered a similar question a few days ago:

> [RealTime database or Firestore to create friends relationship?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76573828/realtime-database-or-firestore-to-create-friends-relationship/76578759#76578759)

It's possible that the following article to also help:

- [How to reduce Firestore costs?](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-reduce-firestore-costs-8cb712473e83)

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Do you think I should worry about Firebase UIDs becoming much longer — up to 128 characters —  in the future? 

At 100 characters long, I think 4 MiB would allow for a very large, but potentially insufficient list of 40,000 users. Also, I read the article, which suggested creating a unique document for every day of the year. Wouldn’t that strategy become untenable with many users after 10 years, when pulling all the documents for a post might invoke 365*10 reads (still better than millions, I know)

Comment: As far as I know, there is no need to make them longer, they are completely unique as they currently are. Furthermore, if you think a document for a year will not be sufficient, then you can create a  document for January-June and another one for July-December, or three January-April, May-August, September-December, and so on.

Comment: Oh, I was wondering because of what I read on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43911234/is-a-firebase-uid-always-28-characters — anyways, I think creating documents based on time is a good solution, but what do you think of creating a new document once the previous document became almost full, say, 0.95 MiB?

Comment: Yes, as soon as reach the limit, create another document.

Comment: Wouldn’t this be more simple/efficient than creating individual documents for specific time periods? Of course, it might be nice to have “likes” sorted by date —— but wouldn’t creating-a-new-document-only-when-the-previous-one-was-almost-full also have the benefit of using the absolute least number of documents necessary?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If you need to read the number of likes, you should read the size of the array that costs only one read.

Comment: I apologize. I think there are two good ways to organize a social network post’s “likes” on Firebase. The first way is to create a new document for a certain period of time (January to June, July to December, etc) — but another way is to just create a new document when the previous document is almost full. Wouldn’t the second way be more efficient and potentially more simple?

Comment: The second option is maximum optimization. If don't care about a few more reads, then the first approach would be cleaner.